# Class definition class name <>

Tags: java, generics

What's the sense of this class definition, what's kind of class is that?

```
class Node<K extends Comparable<? super K>,V>
```

Comment: Please tag your question with appropriate programming language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a generic class definition. It translates to:

- class Node takes two types as parameters: K and V.
- the type K **must** extend the class `Comparable`
- the class `Comparable` itself, in this case, takes some type as parameter, let's call it T.
- type T **must** be a superclass of K.

**Edit**: Ok, since an example was requested, a simple instantiation of this class could be:

```
Node<Integer, String> node = new Node<Integer, String>();
```

Since the `Integer` class implements `Comparable<Integer>` it fits the above description nicely (note that `super` also allows type T to the the same type as K).

V has no constraints, so it can be any type.

Comment: +1 beat me to it by a couple of seconds, I was formatting the code :)

Comment: Okay, so you gave a direct translation of the signature... could you provide an example of a class that could be used for `K`, and maybe an explanation of where this kind of class would be useful?

Comment: It's useful in implementation of Red-Black Tree data structure. http://en.literateprograms.org/Red-black_tree_(Java) But i also would like to know, where else can it be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic class of types `K` and `V`, where `K` is a type that extends `Comparable` of any class that is a superclass of `K`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's from an implementation of a red-black tree designed for explanatory purposes:

[Red-black tree implemented in Java](http://en.literateprograms.org/Red-black_tree_%28Java%29)

Beyond that, it's a class called `Node` that takes parameters K and V, where K extends `Comparable`, which takes a parameter that is itself a superclass of K.

Comment: that's right, it's a class definition taken from that source.