# Java: I don't understand this generics definition at all

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, comparable

I have some sorting methods that in order to work they need to accept an object that has the `compareTo` defined.

The following as part of the generic definition:

```
private static <SomeType extends Comparable<? super SomeType>> 
    void  doSomeSort(SomeType[] a, int left, int right){
```

seems to do the trick.

My problem is that I don't really understand what the
`<SomeType extends Comparable<? super SomeType>>`

actually defines.
It means that you can substiture a type that is an interface that extends Comparable that is instanciated by itself...
I don't get.

Can you please help on clarifying this definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422078/class-definition-class-name/8422157.

Answer (score 3):

This means:

> SomeType is a class that extends `Comparable<SomeType>` or `Comparable<Any type that is a superclass or super interface of SomeType>`.

The reason of `? super SomeType` is that the sort procedure is able to sort an array of SomeType instances if SomeType is able to compare itself to other SomeType instances. If it happens that SomeType extends SomeSuperType, and that any SomeSuperType instance is able to compare itself to other SomeSuperType instances, the sort will compare them without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, all you really need to know is that it means:

```
SomeType x = ...;
SomeType y = ...;
int comparison = x.compareTo(y);
```

will compile.

More precisely, it means that `SomeType` implements `Comparable<T>` for some type `T` which is in the inheritance hierarchy of `SomeType`... without you having to specify what the `T` is but the upshot is that the code above works :)

Comment: But the definition says `extends Comparable`.Not `SomeType implements Comparable`

Comment: @user384706: Generic constraints don't use `implements`, that's all. Heck, `SomeType` *could* be an interface.

Answer (score 1):

It translates to:

- the type `SomeType` must extend **or implement** the class `Comparable`
- the class `Comparable` itself, in this case, takes some type as parameter, let's call it `T`.
- type `T` must be `SomeType` or a superclass of `SomeType`.

A classic type that fits this pattern is `Integer`, since it implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<SomeType extends Comparable<? super SomeType>>
```

Comparable is always of a special template type.
So `Comparable<String>` is something that can be compared to a `String`, `Comparable<BigInteger>` is something that can be compared to a `BigInteger`, and so on.

What's expected here is a `SomeType` which derives from `Comparable<T>`. Meaning that `SomeType` is comparable to other instances. The most trivial thing would be

```
<SomeType extends Comparable<SomeType>>
```

Should be clear till now.
Everything thats now added is a simple `super` keyword.
This means, SomeType needs to be comparable to everything that is of type `SomeType` or anything above in the derivation hierarchy.
This basically has one advantage: You can later derive your own/additional types from SomeType and this method will still be downward compatible!
Awesome, eh?

For example:

```
class SomeTypeSuper { ... }
class SomeType extends SomeTypeSuper { ... }    

// Now, in your code both is valid:
// Asuming the method `yourMethod` expects a `<SomeType extends Comparable<? super SomeType>>` as parameter.

yourMethod(new SomeTypeSuper()); // This wouldn't be valid if we had used Comparable<SomeType>
yourMethod(new SomeType());
```

Comment: `? super SomeType` accepts any class *above* SuperType in the inheritance hierarchy, and not *below*.

Comment: @JBNizet Yep, correct! Obviously was a slip of the pen :/. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Float is a subclass of Number. We could declare it like so:

```
class Float extends Number implements Comparable<Float>
```

But in fact, our Float class is way broader than that. The float class knows how to compare itself with Integers, Bignums, Doubles, etc etc. In fact, our float class knows how to compare itself to *any( number.

```
class Float extends Number implements Comparable<Number>
class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Number>
```

In fact: *any* number class needs to do this, so the real declaration sare

```
class Number implements Comparable<Number>
class Integer extends Number
class Float extends Number
```

Now, the Comparable interface is cool with this. If it wasn't wildcarded, then Floats and Integers wouldn't be able to be Comparable.

But since it is, you can go:

```
Comparable<Number> array[] = new Comparable<Number>[10];
array[0] = Float.getValue(10);     
array[1] = Integer.getValue(11);
sort(array, 0, 1);
```

You can't do this without the >? super T>.

Comment: Your answer seems to be very close to the concept here but has errors.Even your example code is wrong.You can not do `Comparable<Number> array[] = new ..` to begin with.